# How to use Cudnn LSTMP?

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, projection

Usually I use `tf.contrib.cudnn_rnn.CudnnLSTM` (tensorflow 1.15) and want to use LSTMP(LSTM projection) now. I know that `tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell` has LSTMP but that additional training time is too long for me. And I found that [nvidia support LSTMP](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-developer-guide/index.html#features-of-rnn-functions). How to use it on tensorflow(or other ML toolkit)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can alternatively use `tf.contrib.cudnn_rnn.CudnnParamsFormatConverterLSTM` which `CudnnParamsFormatConverterLSTM` is the helper class that converts between params of Cudnn and TF LSTM. You can also set the output dimensionality for the projection matrices using `num_proj`.
Here is the [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/cudnn_rnn/CudnnParamsFormatConverterLSTM) for the detailed documentation of API in TensorFlow 1.15.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! From what I read it's somewhat complicated. Could I just use https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.15.2/tensorflow/contrib/cudnn_rnn/python/ops/cudnn_rnn_ops.py#L1848 ?(there is num_proj in the class) Somehow I failed to import this file like https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.15.2/tensorflow/contrib/cudnn_rnn/python/layers/cudnn_rnn.py#L20 . Can you help me?

Comment: @1258 - did you try importing like this way? 'import tensorflow as tf'
'from tensorflow.contrib.cudnn_rnn import CudnnParamsFormatConverterLSTM'.